# What minimal version of the Google play services apk is required for using google play services library 11.8.0

Tags: google-maps, google-play-services

My application has dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
```

I am trying to figure out the minimum version of the google play services apk required on the device.
I found this library using version code:

> public static final int GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE = 11910000;

to check compatibility but was not able to find to which version of apk it corresponds to

Comment: Could you please clarify the issue? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.